# How to write a complex dispatchPath for a request in a SoapUI project?

Tags: soap, soapui

Until now I used only simple SoapUI projects to mock reponses for my Soap requests, I had a couple of possible responses and a dispatchPath like

```
    <con:dispatchPath>
        def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent)
        def type = holder["//RequestData/type"]
        if( type == "A" )
          return "responseA"
        else if( type == "B" )
          return "responseB"
    </con:dispatchPath>
<con:dispatchStyle>SCRIPT</con:dispatchStyle>
```

But now I have a more complex case and I need to select a response based on multiple fields of the request xml. My question would be, how to do it? Can I write something like the following?

```
def field1 = holder["//RequestData/field1"]
def field2 = holder["//RequestData/field2"]
if( field1 == "A" && field2 = "B" )
```

Where can I find a description of allowed expressions in this dispatchPath?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realized, that it is just a Groovy script, the problem is solved, sorry!